Why are the letters "POS" repeated on Idaho's Treaty Rock?
"Treaty Rock" is a historical site in Post Falls, Idaho. Traditionally it's said to record an 1871 agreement between lumber-mill-builder Frederick Post and Coeur d'Alene chief Andrew Seltice. Chiseled into the rock are the words "June 1, 1871", then "Frederick Post", and then again below the word "Frederick" the letters "Pos" are outlined (but not fully chiseled out). So the whole chiseled part reads: "June 1, 1871 — Frederick Post — Pos."
Photos from 1940 (from the site's NHRP registration form) and 2015 (from Wikipedia) show (faintly/blurrily) what I'm talking about:








My question is, what's the story there? Did Post start chiseling his surname below his given name, then decide it would look better to the right? Did he chisel it to the right, then start again below (maybe to add something like "Post Falls") but abandoned it for some reason halfway through? Was the "Pos" added by someone else, sometime between 1871 and 1940? Was the completed "Post" added by someone else?
Obviously this isn't something you'd be able to figure out from these photos alone; it requires some amount of research and/or local lore. Maybe it's lost in the mists of time. But you never know until you ask!

POS: point of sale = the place where someone pays for something? Could it be that simple? The location of the deal made between the 2 men?

@OldPadawan, not in 1871, no.
